# Magento cache - how to disable this singleton(page identifier) cache?

Tags: blocks, block-cache

When cache is disabled, `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();` is working fine and i am getting *correct page identifier for all pages*.

But when cache is enabled, it is always *returning the page identifier that's loaded firs*t.

I am calling it in phtml files. Should it work fine in block classes?

Any workaround?

---

Update:

Actually all code are being cached somehow AND I cant see any output of new code unless I flush or disable cache. So this does not seem to be an issue of this particular singleton object. On same server, another magento installation/project is fine with cache enabled and I can see uptodate immediately. I am looking into the issue. It might be any other setting or the theme that has come up with some extensions.

Comment: What version of magento EE or CE?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 and we are using a third party theme too and not sure if anything related to the theme is causing this issue.

Comment: Can you try factory method instead of singleton? `Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getIdentifier();`

Comment: I just updated the question. So this is not an issue related to that object anymore, the entire phtml is being cached somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My entire navigation block was being cached and any changes I was making did not reflect on the frontend at all unless the cache are being cleared. But other phtml files were fine.

In my navigation block class I added the following code and it is now working as expected:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->addData(array(   'cache_lifetime' => null ));
}
```

The following link helped me to fix the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032002/1302297